# how to get grand total in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-adapter

please help me i am facing and trouble past more time to these issue in to get grand total on fragment but they call multipal times so please show video and suggest me to find out and solve the problem.its a simple grocery store application for making checking my knowledge please help and possible to share another so quick way to get me solution fast...thanks community support please ..

**[my output link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AG-xTgfF_z5eew09GeMJYLjQ9MptZoEW/view?usp=sharing)**

**[i want similer to these in fragmnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5eeR.png)**

**my Cart fragment code**

```
    public class CartFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateInf{
    
        RecyclerView cartList;
       // public static List<ProductModel> cartModels;
        private List<ProductModel> cartItemList;
        public static TextView tvTotalWithCheckout;
        CartHelper cartHelper;
        public static double grandTotalPlus = 0.0d;
        int cartCount;
        ProductModel productModel;
        UpdateInf updateInf;
    
        public CartFragment() {
    
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                 @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
            cartList = view.findViewById(R.id.cartList);
            tvTotalWithCheckout = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalWithCheckout);
            cartHelper = new CartHelper(getActivity());
            productModel = new ProductModel();
            updateInf = this;
    
    
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            cartList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    
    
    
            //LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.layout_anim_right_to_left);
           // cartList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
           // cartList.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
            //cartList.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    
            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
            cartList.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    
    
            cartItemList = cartHelper.getAllProducts();
    
            MyCartAdapter myCartAdapter = new MyCartAdapter(getActivity(), cartItemList, updateInf);
            cartList.setAdapter(myCartAdapter);
    
           // tvTotalWithCheckout.setText( "\u20B9" + grandTotal(cartItemList));
            Log.e("grandCheckTotal", "setMyCartItem: "+grandTotalPlus);
    
            tvTotalWithCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CheckoutActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
            return view;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            grandTotal(cartItemList);
            Log.e("grandTotal", "setQuantity: "+ grandTotalPlus);
        }
    
        private double grandTotal(List<ProductModel> cartItemList) {
            for (ProductModel model : cartItemList) {
               // Log.e("cartData", "setMyCartItem: " + model.getProductId() + ":" + model.getProductName());
                cartCount = model.getProductQty();
                grandTotalPlus += Double.parseDouble(model.getProductPrice()) * cartCount;
            }
            return grandTotalPlus;
        }
    
    
    
    }


**my adapter code**


public class MyCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCartAdapter.Holder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ProductModel> productModels;
    CartHelper cartHelper;
    ProductModel productModel;
    UpdateInf updateInf;


    public MyCartAdapter(Context context, List<ProductModel> productModels, UpdateInf updateInf) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productModels = productModels;
        cartHelper = new CartHelper(context);
        this.updateInf = updateInf;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_cart_items, parent, false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Holder holder, final int position) {

        productModel = productModels.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(productModels.get(position).getProductImage()).into(holder.cartImgProduct);
        holder.tvProductName.setText(productModels.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.tvProductPrice.setText("\u20B9" + productModels.get(position).getProductPrice());
        holder.tvProductType.setText(productModels.get(position).getProductType());
        holder.tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(productModels.get(position).getProductQty()));


        holder.imgIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //grandTotalPlus = 0.0d;

                int cartIncrementItem = productModels.get(position).getProductQty();
                cartIncrementItem += 1;

                productModels.get(position).setProductQty(cartIncrementItem);
//                double cash = Double.parseDouble(productModels.get(position).getProductPrice()) * productModels.get(position).getProductQty();

                holder.tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(productModels.get(position).getProductQty()));

//                productModels.get(position).setTotalCash(cash);
                cartHelper.updateCart(new ProductModel(productModels.get(position).getProductId(), productModels.get(position).getProductQty()));
                updateInf.setQuantity(cartIncrementItem);


            }
        });

        holder.imgDecrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    int cartDecrementItem = productModels.get(position).getProductQty();

                    if (cartDecrementItem == 1) {

                    } else {
                        cartDecrementItem -= 1;
                        productModels.get(position).setProductQty(cartDecrementItem);
                        holder.tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(productModels.get(position).getProductQty()));
                        updateInf.setQuantity(cartDecrementItem);

                }
                cartHelper.updateCart(new ProductModel(productModels.get(position).getProductId(), productModels.get(position).getProductQty()));
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productModels.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView cartImgProduct, imgRemoveCart, imgIncrement, imgDecrement;
        TextView tvProductName, tvProductPrice, tvProductType, tvQty;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cartImgProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartImgProduct);
            tvProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            tvProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            tvProductType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductType);
            imgIncrement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIncrement);
            imgDecrement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDecrement);
            tvQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvQty);

        }
    }

}
```

My cart helper code

```
public class CartHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "grocery_store";
    private static final String TABLE_CART = "cart";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_TYPE = "product_type";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE = "product_image";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_QTY = "product_qty";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_CASH = "total_cash";


    public CartHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CART_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CART + "(" + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + KEY_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_PRODUCT_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_PRODUCT_QTY + " INTEGER" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CART_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CART);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addToCart(ProductModel productModels) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID, productModels.getProductId());
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_NAME, productModels.getProductName());
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE, productModels.getProductPrice());
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_TYPE, productModels.getProductType());
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE, productModels.getProductImage());
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_QTY,productModels.getProductQty());


        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CART, null, contentValues);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    public List<ProductModel> getAllProducts() {

        List<ProductModel> productModelList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CART;

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
                productModel.setProductId(cursor.getString(0));
                productModel.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
                productModel.setProductPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                productModel.setProductType(cursor.getString(3));
                productModel.setProductImage(cursor.getString(4));
                productModel.setProductQty(cursor.getInt(5));


                productModelList.add(productModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return productModelList;
    }

    public int updateCart(ProductModel productModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_QTY, productModel.getProductQty());
        //values.put(KEY_TOTAL_CASH,productModel.getTotalCash());
        //values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE,productModel.getProductPrice());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CART, values, KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " = ? ",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(productModel.getProductId())});
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteCart(ProductModel productModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CART, KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(productModel.getProductId())});
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your ```CartHelper``` code

Comment: please see my cart helper code @Ra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private double grandTotal(List<ProductModel> cartItemList) {
            grandTotalPlus = 0.0d // Reinitialze to zero
            for (ProductModel model : cartItemList) {
               // Log.e("cartData", "setMyCartItem: " + model.getProductId() + ":" + model.getProductName());
                cartCount = model.getProductQty();
                grandTotalPlus += Double.parseDouble(model.getProductPrice()) * cartCount;
            }
            return grandTotalPlus;
        }
```

`grandtotalplus` is a static variable its value is never reset when you leave the page, so its value is 50 the very first time when you visit cart page. after that when you go back and add more item and then come back to cart page it still has the value 50 and you start to add over it. That is why you are getting 135.

Comment: so mean that remove static variable and convert them into private right ?

Comment: yes. you can make it non-static or keep if you want to keep it static then you need to reinitialize it to 0.0 before calculating grand total.